# SQLAlchemy: FROM entry still present in correlated subquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build the following query (to be used as a subquery with a containing query that defines an alias named `tbl_outer`) with SQLAlchemy:

```sql
SELECT max(tbl.ts) AS max_1
FROM tbl
WHERE tbl.id = tbl_outer.id
```

As I read the documentation, the correct way to prevent `tbl_outer` references from being present in the FROM clause is `query = query.correlate(tbl_outer)`.
However, instead, I'm getting this, as if `correlate()` had not been called at all:

```sql
SELECT max(tbl.ts) AS max_1
FROM tbl, tbl AS tbl_outer
WHERE tbl.id = tbl_outer.id
```

A minimal reproducer follows:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as sa_orm

engine  = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///memory')
meta    = sa.MetaData(bind=engine)
table   = sa.Table('tbl', meta, sa.Column('id', sa.Integer), sa.Column('ts', sa.Integer))
session = sa_orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
meta.create_all()

tbl_outer = table.alias('tbl_outer')

subquery = session.query(sa.func.max(table.columns.ts)).filter(table.columns.id == tbl_outer.columns.id)

print "=== BEFORE CORRELATION:"
print str(subquery)

print "=== AFTER CORRELATION:"
print str(subquery.correlate(tbl_outer))
```

---

As I read [the documentation for correlate()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.correlate), and [other answers describing its correct use here on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056049/how-to-specify-the-from-tables-in-sqlalchemy-subqueries), I would expect this `correlate(tbl_outer)` call to remove `tbl AS tbl_outer` from the `FROM` clause of the generated SQL; however, it does not do so in practice.

I've received the above results with SQLAlchemy 1.0.8. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

**This is a feature, not a bug, introduced in SQLAlchemy 0.8.**

Prior to 0.8, SQLAlchemy could generate content that wouldn't parse as valid SQL. After 0.8, [correlation is only performed in context](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/changelog/migration_08.html#correlation-is-now-always-context-specific).

In my real code, I was testing code that generated a WHERE clauses for my outer query by taking those clauses out of context. As of SQLAlchemy 0.8, WHERE clauses can only be guaranteed to accurately render to text in accurate larger context.